# How to calculate time and memory taken by code executed at node js command prompt

Tags: node.js

I want to test factorial program in node js environment and to calculate total time and memory taken to execute the code

Answer (score 0):

To measure time there are different ways.

From command line you can use time command:

```
$ time node ./script.js
```

To measure specific parts of code:

```
console.time('DEBUG')
// your code here
console.timeEnd('DEBUG')
```

Also you can use dates:

```
let t1 = new Date();
// your code here
let t2 = new Date();
console.log(t2-t1);
```

For memory use:

- [node-men watch](https://github.com/lloyd/node-memwatch)
- [htop](http://hisham.hm/htop/)